# mv-expand operator in Azure Data Explorer not working as expected for JSON Array

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to follow the instructions in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language#ingest-json-records-containing-arrays) to ingest a JSON array and create records for each item in the array in Azure Data Explorer but things aren't behaving as expected.

My intermediate table has some top level fields that I want carried over and that is working but all of the fields from the array are just blank.

```
.create function RecordsExpandTest() {
    records_intermediate_test
    | mv-expand records_test = answers
    | project
        fullraw = tostring(fullraw),
        question = tostring(question),
        question_class = tostring(question_class),
        question_raw = tostring(question_raw),
        answer_class = tostring(answers["class"]),
        answer_type = tostring(answers["type"]),
        answer_raw = tostring(answers["raw"]),
        request_time = todatetime(request_time)
}
```

When I ingest a row into my intermediate table (records_intermediate_test) that has an array of 3 answers, 3 rows are created in the final table (records_test) but all of the field's related to answers are empty even though in the source data they are not.

Create for intermediate table:

```
.create table records_intermediate_test(fullraw: string, question: string, question_class: string, question_raw: string, answers : dynamic, request_time: datetime)
```

Create for final table:

```
.create table records_test(fullraw: string, question: string, question_class: string, question_raw: string, answer_class : string, answer_type: string, answer_raw : string, request_time: datetime)
```

Alter table that applies the mv-expand:

```
.alter table records_test policy update @'[{"Source": "records_intermediate_test", "Query": "RecordsExpandTest()", "IsEnabled": "True"}]'
```

Sample row from records_intermediate_test

```
"fullraw": TEST,
"question": TEST,
"question_class": TEST,
"answers": [
    {
        "class": "C",
        "type": "C",
        "raw": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "type": "B",
        "raw": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "type": "A",
        "raw": "TEST"
    }
],
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z
```

Sample row from records_test

```
"fullraw": TEST,
"question": TEST,
"question_class": TEST,
"answer_class": ,
"answer_type": ,
"answers_raw": ,
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z
```

^Repeated 3 times in the table

Expected rows from records_test

```
"fullraw": TEST,
"question": TEST,
"question_class": TEST,
"answer_class": A,
"answer_type": A,
"answers_raw": TEST,
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z

"fullraw": TEST,
"question": TEST,
"question_class": TEST,
"answer_class": B,
"answer_type": B,
"answers_raw": TEST,
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z

"fullraw": TEST,
"question": TEST,
"question_class": TEST,
"answer_class": C,
"answer_type": C,
"answers_raw": TEST,
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z
```

The intermediate table's input always includes an array with 1 question in it. This is the mapping:

```
.create table records_intermediate_test ingestion json mapping 'mappingtest' 
'['
'   { "column" : "fullraw", "Properties":{"Path":"$.fullraw"}},'
'   { "column" : "question", "Properties" {"Path":"$.question[0].question"}},'
'   { "column" : "question_class", "Properties":{"Path":"$.question[0].class"}},'
'   { "column" : "question_raw", "Properties":{"Path":"$.question[0].raw"}},'
'   { "column" : "answers", "Properties":{"Path":"$.answers"}},'
    '   { "column" : "request_time", "Properties":{"Path":"$.request_time"}}'
']'
```

Sample raw JSON input for the records_intermediate_test table:

```
{
"fullraw": "TEST",
"question": "TEST",
"question_class": "TEST",
"answers": [
    {
        "class": "C",
        "type": "C",
        "raw": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "class": "B",
        "type": "B",
        "raw": "TEST"
    },
    {
        "class": "A",
        "type": "A",
        "raw": "TEST"
    }
],
"request_time": 2019-01-01T10:07:49.0105654Z
}
```

Comment: you may want to include a sample input so that it's clearer how your data looks like and what may be wrong. without understanding the contents of `records_intermediate_test`, trying to help you is like shot in the dark

Comment: Edited to show more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function used by update policy to include those fields:

```
.create function RecordsExpandTest() {
records_intermediate_test
| mv-expand records_test = answers
| project
    fullraw = tostring(fullraw),
    question = tostring(question),
    question_class = tostring(question_class),
    question_raw = tostring(question_raw),
    answer_class = tostring(answers["class"]),
    answer_type = tostring(answers["type"]),
    answer_raw = tostring(answers["raw"]),
    request_time = todatetime(request_time),
    MyTopLevelField
}
```

Make sure intermediate table and target table fit your schema:

```
.create table RawEvents ingestion json mapping 'RawEventMapping' '[{"column":"Answers","path":"$.answers"}, {"column":"MyTopLevelField","path":"$.myTopLevelField"}]'
```

Comment: I added additional details to the question. It isn't the toplevel fields I'm having issues with those are being mapped correctly. It is the fields within the objects in the array that aren't mapping.

Comment: it looks like this may be related to the fact you're renaming the column as part of `mv-expand`ing it: you're doing `mv-expand records_test = answers`, and then trying to reference `answers["raw"]` (for example), instead of referencing `records_test["raw"])` (or removing the rename). regardless, you don't need to explicitly cast columns which aren't `dynamic` (e.g. if `request_time` is already of type `datetime`, just project it as-is, instead of projecting `request_time = todatetime(request_time)`. same for `fullraw`, `questions`, etc.

Comment: You were right that when I don't rename it isn't a problem, so I did like you suggested and did the renaming in the mapping. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Keren's answer was along the right lines. I should have only been mapping the field's within the array and just left the other ones as is. This is my expand function that worked:

```
.create function RecordsExpandTest() {
    dns_records_intermediate
    | mv-expand dns_records = answers
     | project
        request_time,
        fullraw,
        question_class,
        question,
        question_raw,
        answer_class = tostring(answers.class),
        answer_raw = tostring(answers.raw),
        answer_type = tostring(answers.type)
}
```

With this new mapping when I insert an entry into the records_intermediate_test with an array of 3 answers 1 record is created in records_intermediate_test and 3 in records_test with all the fields mapped as expected.

Also answers["raw"] format also works.